# how to change a CTE to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code below that is a CTE looking at a view Within a CTE within a CTE.
i trying to re code this ( not my code) to have a view look at a view so i can use in a application that dose not support CTEs

```
    ;
WITH C1 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, ts, Type
            ,e=CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK, Type ORDER BY LTOdteVacatingDate) END
            ,s=CASE Type WHEN -1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK, Type ORDER BY LTOdteOccupiedDate) END
            ,se=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK ORDER BY ts, Type DESC)
        FROM dav.LTOwCompany
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (1, LTOdteOccupiedDate), (-1, LTOdteVacatingDate)) a(Type, ts)
        ),

    C3 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, ts
            ,grpnm=FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK ORDER BY ts)-1) / 2 + 1)
        FROM C1
        WHERE COALESCE(s-(se-s)-1, (se-e)-e) = 0),
    -- C1, C2, C3, C4 combined remove the overlapping date periods
    C4 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, datestart=MIN(ts), dateend=MAX(ts)
        FROM C3
        GROUP BY CTenancyPK, grpnm, CdblRentalAmount)


SELECT qryAddress.Address, CTenancyPK, VoidDateStart=MIN(newdate), VoidDateEnd=MAX(newdate),CdblRentalAmount,VoidCost = (CdblRentalAmount * 12 / 365) * case when '2018-04-01' between MIN(newdate) and MAX(newdate) then  datediff(dd,'2018-04-01',MAX(newdate)+1)
else datediff(dd,MIN(newdate),MAX(newdate)+1)
end ,
case when '2018-04-01' between MIN(newdate) and MAX(newdate) then  datediff(dd,'2018-04-01',MAX(newdate)+1)
else datediff(dd,MIN(newdate),MAX(newdate)+1)
end as NoDays

FROM (
    SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, newdate
        ,rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK ORDER BY newdate) / 2
    FROM C4 a
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (datestart-1),(dateend+1)) b(newdate)
    ) a
Join Tenancy on Tenancy.TenancyPK = CTenancyPK
Join Property on Property.PropertyPK = Tenancy.PropertyFK
Join qryAddress on qryAddress.AddressPK = Property.AddressFK

GROUP BY Address,CTenancyPK, rn, CdblRentalAmount
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 and MAX(newdate) >= '2018-04-01' 
ORDER BY CTenancyPK, Voiddatestart;
```

I want to see is something like this

```
SELECT qryAddress.Address, CTenancyPK, VoidDateStart=MIN(newdate), VoidDateEnd=MAX(newdate),CdblRentalAmount,VoidCost = (CdblRentalAmount * 12 / 365) * case when '2018-04-01' between MIN(newdate) and MAX(newdate) then  datediff(dd,'2018-04-01',MAX(newdate)+1)
else datediff(dd,MIN(newdate),MAX(newdate)+1)
end ,
case when '2018-04-01' between MIN(newdate) and MAX(newdate) then  datediff(dd,'2018-04-01',MAX(newdate)+1)
else datediff(dd,MIN(newdate),MAX(newdate)+1)
end as NoDays

FROM Dav.LTOvLTO 
-- New view that dose the CTE calculation and looks at Dav.LTOwCompany

Join Tenancy on Tenancy.TenancyPK = CTenancyPK
Join Property on Property.PropertyPK = Tenancy.PropertyFK
Join qryAddress on qryAddress.AddressPK = Property.AddressFK
GROUP BY Address,CTenancyPK, rn, CdblRentalAmount
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 and MAX(newdate) >= '2018-04-01' 
ORDER BY CTenancyPK, Voiddatestart;
```

Comment: `an application that dose not support CTEs` what does that mean? This is just a SQL query. Any application will simply execute it as is. Are you trying to get an ORM or a reporting tool to generate something equivalent to the CTEs perhaps?

Comment: You do NOT want to create a view that looks at another view. This is known as nested views and will cripple the performance of your code. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: the application reads sql but its in a very strict manner it dont no run CTEs, if u want to know more about the application say but i dont think thats the point

Comment: @JD_123 the application doesn't run the query, the server does. This is the point - why *can't* you use a CTE in the first place? Why not create a view that uses CTEs?

Comment: @SeanLange oh my thank you, what would u recommend

Comment: @JD_123 what is your *actual* problem? You haven't explained that yet. `I can't use CTEs` isn't a problem statement. *Why* can't you use perfectly valid syntax? Some kinds of queries are impossible without CTEs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in my case its different Trust me, and i dont have the rights to create a view by code or i would i have to use the Create view tool and with that it dont let me do it in SSMS

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i can use CTE in SSMS but int the application i cant so i need to use a view do this query so that it works it the application im using

Comment: This question has [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) written all over it.

Comment: What kind of application prevents you from using a cte in a query? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: @SeanLange lol yeah spot on and this application is crap dont get me started, i get paid to work with it so i have to try

Comment: @JD_123 we don't though, and we can't guess. If you can't explain what you want, you won't get any answers

Comment: Now, you may have a report-builder type of application, like SSRS's report builder. In that case you could just write the raw SQL, or you could create a Dataset that others can use in their queries, using the simplified query builder.

Comment: Or you may have an application that tries to *parse* the SQL query and display it graphically, failing with CTEs. SSMS's query builder fails on that too. That's a completely different problem. What is your *actual* case?

Comment: its a application, that has the ability to run some sql but with strict rules and dosent not work with every bit of code one example are CTEs, if this is hard to answer with out the knowledge of the whole application then answer this. Can you rewrite these CTEs so that i dont have to use them at all

Comment: Yes that could be rewritten to not use those CTEs. It would be rather painful but it can be done. They would essentially become subqueries instead of ctes.

Comment: The naming conventions and lack of good, consistent text formatting is making my eyes scream out in pain.

Comment: @seanlange thats what im doing now its quite hard but im nearly done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTEs with views:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
WITH C1 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, ts, Type
            ,e=CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK, Type ORDER BY LTOdteVacatingDate) END
            ,s=CASE Type WHEN -1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK, Type ORDER BY LTOdteOccupiedDate) END
            ,se=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK ORDER BY ts, Type DESC)
        FROM dav.LTOwCompany
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (1, LTOdteOccupiedDate), (-1, LTOdteVacatingDate)) a(Type, ts)
        ),

    C3 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, ts
            ,grpnm=FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTenancyPK ORDER BY ts)-1) / 2 + 1)
        FROM C1
        WHERE COALESCE(s-(se-s)-1, (se-e)-e) = 0),
    -- C1, C2, C3, C4 combined remove the overlapping date periods
    C4 AS (
        SELECT CTenancyPK,CdblRentalAmount, datestart=MIN(ts), dateend=MAX(ts)
        FROM C3
        GROUP BY CTenancyPK, grpnm, CdblRentalAmount)
    SELECT *
    FROM c4;
```

Comment: I dont have the privileges to create a view like that i have to create a view by using object explorer within SSMS

Comment: @JD_123 SSMS object explorer doesn't create views. The query designer generates *query strings*. If you can use the query designer to create a view, you can just write the `CREATE VIEW` statement itself

Comment: When using create view code as answered i get this error. "incorrect statement "create view" must be the only statment in the batch"

Comment: The correct syntax is `CREATE VIEW v AS WITH c1(...) SELECT * FROM c4;`